# How to get autocomplete result class name in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, kohana-3

I have tried lots of code but I can't get class name which come from autocomplete result.

My code is:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() 
        {
     $("#city").autocomplete("<?php echo Kohana::$base_url;?>/admin/restaurant/get_city_list", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    selectFirst: false,

          });

           });
```

and my result come in this div:

```
          <div class="ac_results">City Name</div>
```

Now how to get autocomplete class name in jQuery?

I have try `.find()`, `.attr('class')`, `.hasClass()`.

But it's not working.

Comment: Are you able to add a reply handler to that `autocomplete` call? Where are you adding your `find`, `attr` call at the moment? Please edit your question to make that bit clear.

Comment: How does the div look like with autocomplete?

Comment: its like dropdown of city

Comment: I think that this is a DOM problem, u want capture the value of the div? or what? I don't understand

Comment: i want to capture the div class name which come in result by jquery